# Python - What is the use of * operator on lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

I just came over a python program asking for output. The code was :

```
l=[]*100
for i in range (100):
l.append(i+1)
flag=0
k=108
for i in range(100):
if(k==l[i]):
    print("Element is present at position",i)
    flag=1
    break
if(flag==0):
print("Element is not present in the given list")
```

My question is what does the list l=[]*100 do?

Besides when I am executing this code the answer I get is : "Element is not present in the given list". But the answer given is 100 which I think is not possible.
Someone please help

Comment: It multiplies a list by copying its item references (not the items).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have been way quicker for you to start up a Python session and try it.  `[]*100` does nothing at all.  The `*100` is totally useless.  If you say `[0]*100`, then you get a list with 100 zeros, but 100 times an empty list is still an empty list.

Comment: Okay then how is the output 100?

Comment: By the way thanks for the answer

Comment: The `for` loop will put 100 elements into `l`, one at a time.